# Why these CSS rules are not applied

Tags: css, web

I was trying to make this [parallax-website](https://jolly-kalam-23776e.netlify.app/parallaxsite/). In the CSS I am defining properties for *.image1* . So I wrote down properties and then just below it I again wrote some properties for the same class *.image1*. But only the ~ opacity, position (from 1st) and other properties defined (from 2 time) were applied. I checked the it using Inspect Element and all other properties were cut down. I am not able to  understand why this is happening. Please help me.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  color: #666;
}

.image1 {
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  opacity: 0.70;
}

.image1 {
  background: url('https://jolly-kalam-23776e.netlify.app/parallaxsite/img/image1.jpg');
  min-height: 100%;
}

.text-box-image1 {
  position: absolute;
  /* To bring that box in center */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.text-image1 {
  font-size: 27px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #111;
  padding: 20px;
}

.section-one {
  padding: 50px 80px;
}

.section-one .heading {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 20px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image1">
  <div class="text-box-image1">
    <span class="text-image1">PARALLAX WEBSITE</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _I checked the it using Inspect Element and all other properties were cut down_ Aren't you able to see what rules are blocking yours from being applied? You can use the inspector to figure it out.

Comment: @melancia I can see what properties are cut down, but I don't know why are they being cut down, I mean I am writing different properties in both cases, so why are being ruled out.

Comment: If you check the "computed" tab on the styles for the element, you can see where your properties are being overruled (ie: what other CSS set is doing it).

Comment: @melancia Thank you, I figured out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to mention background image as "background-image". You are declaring background property individually. or you can write like that way :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  color: #666;
}


.image1 {
  background: url('https://jolly-kalam-23776e.netlify.app/parallaxsite/img/image1.jpg') no-repeat fixed center center;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.70;
  position: relative;
}

.text-box-image1 {
  position: absolute;
  /* To bring that box in center */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.text-image1 {
  font-size: 27px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #111;
  padding: 20px;
}

.section-one {
  padding: 50px 80px;
}

.section-one .heading {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 20px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image1">
  <div class="text-box-image1">
    <span class="text-image1">PARALLAX WEBSITE</span>
  </div>
</div>
```